# Could you explain "Miracast screen's fundamental'?

Tags: android, frameworks, mirroring

I need to find principle of the Miracast and android.

And especially, I want to find that "How Miracast api send cellphone's screen and Where is it?"

Additionally, I also wonder What is the mQueueBuffer in SurfaceMediaSource.cpp and

Who fill this buffer

Answer (score 0):

I would think that if you are looking for definition of what [Miracast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) is you should just hit up wikipedia and get an understanding of what it is underneath.

Miracast is built into several different phones, but it is a hardware feature design as well as a software component (I believe, but you will find after research).  Some phone models support it right now while others don't.